# Please supply some helpful links to a user when their question is closed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, notifications, close-reasons

There are quite a few users that are learning the system the hard way. And many others that do not know why a question he asked was closed as "Not Programming Related" or "Not a Real Question"

What I suggest is a notification to the owner of the question similar to the badge notification.

#### Example:

> Your question "Title here" was closed as "Not Programming Related". You can read up on the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) what kind of questions you can ask.

This could also apply to down votes and other things that are happening to you and could help you along your way.

These would be one time notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know some people find the notification alerts annoying, but myself think they aren't used enough. I would love to see more of those alerts so that I could keep better track of what is happening on the site as I am using it. They aren't terribly obtrusive and they are simple enough to dismiss.

Comment: These would be one time notifications.

Comment: I don't see any issue with that Olafur.

Answer (score 3):

Questions closed now have an explanation appended to the footer of the post with the close reason as well as a link to the site's FAQ.

> #### closed as off topic by Camazotz, Ah Pukuh, Buluc Chabtan, Ah Tabai, Ixtab Dec 21 at 11:58
>
> Questions on Maya Be Well are expected to generally relate to architecture, language or Mayan related culture, within the scope defined in the faq. See the FAQ.

This gives the person asking the question some information as to why their question was sphinctered up and if they feel particularly victimised, a list of people to go frothing at the mouth to.

This also allows for another boilerplate message for users to not read and ask further questions on the site meta.

Comment: *"...sphinctered...victimised...frothing at the mouth..."* Do you, maybe, need a vacation... or something? O.o

Comment: O Buluc Chabtan, *why* did you choose to close my question? (In your infinite wisdom, of course? I'm just asking nicely.)